# Google Apps Script Batch Executes with Unexpected Timing

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

The following code results in a blank sheet, assumably due to .clear() executing last, even though it's listed first?

```
        const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
        var contractSheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
        contractSheet.clear();

        const body = {requests: [{pasteData: {html: true, data: table[0], coordinate: {sheetId: ss.getSheetByName(sheetName).getSheetId()}}}]};
        Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate(body, ss.getId());
```

If I remove the .clear() the script runs and populates the sheet fine. But I need to clear the sheet before loading the new data from the final batch request.

Any ideas would be much appreciated. :-)

Answer (score 4):

In this case, how about using `SpreadsheetApp.flush()` in your script as follows? I thought that after `clear()` was run, it is required to reflect it and request the batchUpdate method of Sheets API.

#### Modified script:

```
const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var contractSheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
contractSheet.clear();

SpreadsheetApp.flush(); // Added

const body = {requests: [{pasteData: {html: true, data: table[0], coordinate: {sheetId: ss.getSheetByName(sheetName).getSheetId()}}}]};
Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate(body, ss.getId());
```

#### Reference:

- [flush()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#flush)

Comment: Perfect! Thank you @Tanaike