# google apps script async await on Sheets api

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I'm copying a range between spreadsheets (60k lines x 21 columns) and moved from using range.setValues() into Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.update() due to performance issues. The Sheets services is indeed faster.

However it seems I need to wait for the Sheets... to terminate before continuing with the code (doing additional format in the target range).

I set async to the function and added an await to the Sheets call but the script stops working just in this line (the Sheets...update not being executed)

```
async function pullRange() {
   ...

   result = await Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.update(..., ..., ...);
   ...
   //continue working after sheet values have been updated
}
```

Is there a workaround using async / await or any other option?

The original code was something like this:

```
function pullRange() {
   ...

   result = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.update(..., ..., ...);
   ...
   targetRange.setHorizontalAlignment('center'); 
  // after this instruction the sheet suddenly has twice the lines it should
  // (120k instead of 60k.) 
  // Somehow this instruction is being performed before the end of the Sheets....update()


}
```

To solve this issue is why I tried using async/await

Comment: In the current stage, Google Apps Script runs with the synchronous process. So I cannot understand about the situation of `However it seems I need to wait for the Sheets... to terminate before continuing with the code`. I apologize for this. Can I ask you about the detail of your current issue?

Comment: How much data are you writing, and how much calculation is done based on the cells you're writing into? There's a small chance you may benefit from a call to `SpreadsheetApp.flush()`, though honestly I would expect the Apps Script library to invoke similar write-buffer-flushing code in the backend for a subset of its methods.

Comment: @Tanaike I've added some additional background in the question. As said, at the end of the script the targetSheet ends up having 60k raw lines (no format or content) below the data. This behavior didn't occur when I used the range.setValues()

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying and adding more information, I thought that this thread might be the answer for your current issue. https://stackoverflow.com/q/66862335 So, when your additional script is used, please put `SpreadsheetApp.flush()` just after `result = `. This has already been mentioned by @tehhowch 's comment.

Comment: Thank you @techowch @Tanaike. The `SpreadsheetApp.flush()` did the work.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. From your replying, I flagged this question as the duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/66862335 .